# What does "champion supporter" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, learning

I've been studying English and found an expression **champion supporter** in the following sentence.

> Faced with a global audience, British television needs its champion supporters.

Does the "champion supporter" mean someone who supports a lot?

Comment: Where did you see this? It could mean a few related things: either a supporter who is a champion at something, or a  supporter who champions British television, or as you say a particularly good supporter. It's not a set expression so it doesn't have a clear meaning.

Comment: Not quite clear what the entire sentence means (why does a global audience require  British TV to have supporters?) but yes, **champion** can be used to indicate a large degree of commitment. A worthy cause can have **champion donors**, for example.

Comment: I found it in a sample ietls reading test. [link](https://ielts-up.com/reading/academic-reading-sample-1.3.html)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to analyze "unusual" text that probably didn't even come from a native Anglophone

Answer (score 1):

See this definition of "champion" from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/champion#dictionary-entry-1):

> 4: one that does battle for another's rights or honor
> *God will raise me up a champion
>
> —Sir Walter Scott*

So "champion supporters" are supporters who do battle on behalf of British television. In this case the "battle" is figurative, of course: posting to social media, petitioning legislators, etc.

The quoted line comes from a [talk](https://ielts-up.com/reading/academic-reading-sample-1.3.html) by Armando Iannucci, an award-winning TV producer. He further said

> If public service broadcasting - one of the best things we've ever done creatively as a country - if it was a car industry, our ministers would be out championing it overseas, trying to win contracts, boasting of the British jobs that would bring.

This describes the kind of supporting activities that would be undertaken by these champions.

Comment: This is probably the intended sense of *champion* here, but much of what champions, in that sense, do is also what supporters do anyway. It is thus less than clear what is supposed to distinguish champion supporter from the supporters who are not champion supporters. Chances are that this is not very clear in the author's mind either; the word *champion* was probably thrown in without much thought.

Comment: @jsw29 At first I thought it was redundant and included that in my answer. But I support lots of charities by sending them donations, and I wouldn't consider myself a champion. Champions are the ones who actively work on behalf of the charities. At the borderline, someone who gives enough to get a building named after them might be considered a champion.

Comment: Cound u look through it for more information? i just found it in a sample ielts test on the internet [link](https://ielts-up.com/reading/academic-reading-sample-1.3.html)

Comment: I've added a clarifying statement that he said.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context from the OP, this example provides little information from which to extrapolate meaning. However, it seems to infer a base of already-established supporters on which it will need to rely, in order to address this larger global audience.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I found it in a sample ielts reading test. [link](https://ielts-up.com/reading/academic-reading-sample-1.3.html)